# How to get photos by paging from facebook with Javascript API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have 50 photos but response gets 10.I use next property and unfortunately get one photo.
How can I use paging ?

```
function getPhotosByAlbumId(albumId) {

    FB.api('/' + albumId + "/photos", function (resp) {
        console.log('Photos', resp);
        var photos = resp.data;

        var pagingAfter = resp.paging.cursors.after;
        var pagingBefore = resp.paging.cursors.before;
        var next = resp.paging.next;
        debugger;
        // var next = resp.paging.next.substring(0, resp.paging.next.indexOf('&after'));
       setPhotos(photos, albumId);
   });
   FB.api('/' +next , function (resp) {
      debugger;
      console.log('nexttt', resp);

  });
}
```